# I want a checkbox to be checked by default,

Tags: php

When will I update my semester that time by default a checkbox to be  checked  how it possible ?

```
<select name="semester">
  <option value="">Select Semester</option>
  <option value="1">Semester 1</option>
  <option value="2">Semester 2</option>
  <option value="3">Semester 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do code know you've selected which semester ?

Comment: You will need to show the PHP code so we can see what data is controlling which semester you want to select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
<select name="semester">
            <option value="">Select Semester</option>
            <option value="1" <?php if($data['semester']==1){echo 'selected';}?>>Semester 1</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if($data['semester']==2){echo 'selected';}?>>Semester 2</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if($data['semester']==3){echo 'selected';}?>>Semester 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `selected` attribute.

```
<select name="semester">
     <option value="">Select Semester</option>
     <option value="1" selected="selected">Semester 1</option>
     <option value="2">Semester 2</option>
     <option value="3">Semester 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want to do it by php not html  such as Rahim is a studen of 1s semister I want to update his semister when I will update that time his semister by default checked semister 1st

Comment: @OmarFaruk I've made a generic PHP example and posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select `semester 2` so here you go:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="semester">
  <option value="">Select Semester</option>
  <option value="1">Semester 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Semester 2</option>
  <option value="3">Semester 3</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("select option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "Semester 2")
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,it possible. you have to use `selected` in `<option>`

```
<select name="semester">
        <option value="">Select Semester</option>
        <option value="1" selected>Semester 1</option>
        <option value="2">Semester 2</option>
        <option value="3">Semester 3</option>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dave17/r58tc7c7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="1" <?= ($value=='1')?'selected':"" ?>>Semester 1</option>
<option value="2" <?= ($value=='2')?'selected':"" ?>>Semester 2</option>
<option value="3" <?= ($value=='3')?'selected':"" ?>>Semester 3</option>
```

you can get the value form database or session,

Answer (score 0):

We really need your specific PHP code to help, but perhaps this generic example will show you how to do this when you have your data and your desired value:

```
<?php
    //Your array of data
    $myData = array(
        '1' => 'Semester 1',
        '2' => 'Semester 2',
        '3' => 'Semester 3');

    //The value you want to be selected
    $myValue = "2";
?>

<select name="semester">
    <option value="">Select Semester</option>
        <?php
            foreach($myData as $key => $value){
                echo ('<option value="'.$key.'"' );
                if( $myValue == $key){
                    echo( ' selected="selected" ');
                }
                echo ('>'.$value.'</option');
                echo "\n";
            }
        ?>
</select>
```